# Unions of orbits of dimension $\leq n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a complex linear algebraic group acting on a smooth complex projective variety $X$ with finitely many orbits. Note that each $G$-orbit is a smooth locally closed subvariety of $X$.

For a non-negative integer $n$, define $X_n$ to be the union of all $G$-orbits of dimension $\leq n$. I am looking for a reference addressing the following question.

Under what additional hypotheses (on $G$, $X$, the action, etc.) can we conclude that $X_n$ is a smooth submanifold of $X$?

Comment: "Under what additional hypotheses (on $G$, $X$, the action, etc.) can we conclude that $X_n$ is a smooth submanifold of $X$?"  Almost never.  Obviously this is true if $X$ is homogeneous, i.e., there is only one orbit.  But already, for the obvious action of an $n$-dimensional torus on complex projective $n$-space, this fails (except if $n$ equals $1$).

Comment: I find it hard to imagine how to motivate this condition. I think that $X_n$ is the support of a natural closed subscheme, but why smooth? And @JasonStarr: perhaps the order of quantifiers is meant to be that, given $X$, for which $n$ is this true?

Comment: Yes, the question would certainly benefit from some motivation. Mine is somewhat esoteric. I have a class of infinite-dimensional spaces acted upon by an algebraic group, and I am trying to generate a reasonable-looking filtration from the orbit-stratification. My first thought was to filter according to orbit dimension, and it would be convenient for my calculation to have everything in the filtration be a smooth subvariety. This is the case in one of the examples I am considering. It is unclear whether this holds in my remaining examples.

Comment: Also, since there are some results for unions of orbits with stabilizer belonging to a fixed conjugacy class for compact group actions, I thought it might be possible to say something general about $X_n$ under nice hypotheses. Still, it is often dangerous to expect something smooth when taking unions of orbits.